# Not able to parse variable other than string using Moya in swift

Tags: ios, swift, moya

I am working on an iOS project in Swift. I used [Moya](https://github.com/Moya/Moya) framework for API handling and parsing. It works perfectly. But when I try to parse varibles other than string it shows me en error:

> "Missing argument for parameter 'transformation' in call"

Here is my mapper class

```
import Mapper

class MyMapperClaa:Mappable {
    var dateVariable: NSDate?

    required init(map: Mapper) throws{
        try dateVariable = map.from("date")
    }
}
```

Comment: check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38668279/swift-and-objectmapper-nsdate-with-min-value

Comment: Iam using Moya-ModelMapper not ObjectMapper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry, you are using this lib: https://github.com/lyft/mapper. from example there:

```
private func extractDate(object: Any?) throws -> Date {
  guard let rawDate = object as? String else {
    throw MapperError.convertibleError(value: object, type: Date.self)
  }
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "your date format"

    if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: rawDate)  {
        return date
    } else {
      throw MapperError.convertibleError(value: object, type: Date.self)
    }

}

struct DateModel: Mappable {
  let date: Date

  init(map: Mapper) throws {
    try date = map.from("date", transformation: extractDate)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Created an extension for Date and its worked for me

```
extension Date:Convertible
{
    public static func fromMap(_ value: Any) throws -> Date {
        guard let rawDate = value as? String else {
            throw MapperError.convertibleError(value: value, type: Date.self)
        }
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

        if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: rawDate)  {
            return date
        } else {
            throw MapperError.convertibleError(value: value, type: Date.self)
        }


    }
```

}